# getting in PhpSpreadsheet a named range defined in Libre OFfice calc

Tags: php, libreoffice-calc, phpspreadsheet

I am loading a Libre Office spreadsheet which has a named range defined on the Libre Office calc side:

```
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Ods();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load("test.ods");
```

Works great so far to retrieve the spreadsheet (as simple as the two statements above), except that I do not get the named range:

```
$namedRange = $spreadsheet->getNamedRanges();
```

$namedRange above is an empty array. From reading the doc, I see I can define a range on the php side, but it is unclear whether PhpSpreadsheet is able to get ranges defined on the Libre Office calc side,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Based on reading https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/develop/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Ods.php there is no support for named ranges in the ODS reader. In general it seems that the support for features in the ODS reader is very limited.

Comment: OK thanks ! Indeed I can see the xls (7500 lines) and xlsx (2000 lines) have more features implemented than the ods one (820 lines). Still I can retrieve cells by range, so will be very useful to me :-)